# How should I edit my Game Maker questions to improve them?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have three questions that I have asked on the main site. Every single one of them have been downvoted quite heavily, in my opinion, to the point that I am longer allowed to ask questions (I checked out of curiosity; I am not interested in asking anything else right now). I asked in chat twice (and some nice people upvoted the questions to try and counter-balance what they felt were unfair voting practices) and was told that there are no detectable issues in my questions besides simple things that I can't fix myself anyways (one of the questions is relevant to a mod so the precise software version is unknown).

Now I don't care too much about downvotes, but it does concern me that with only three questions I am question banned, especially when only one of them is explicitly relevant towards what version of software was used. Everything else are only general questions about game maker or only mention the mod as useful context with little relevancy as to what the issue I was having was. As some people in chat also mentioned there is a large stigma towards users of game maker which could also contribute to why it is attracting down voters.

These are the questions I have posted on the site so far:

- [Does Game Maker use use intrinsic or extrinsic rotations?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131729/do-game-makers-3d-rotation-transformations-use-intrinsic-or-extrinsic-rotations)
- [Camera not working in a Game Maker mod I am creating](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131663/camera-not-taking-over-in-a-mod-of-a-game-maker-i-am-creating)
- [Why won't my model display fully in a mod made with an older version of GameMaker?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131329/why-wont-my-model-display-fully-in-a-mod-made-with-an-older-version-of-gamemake)

Comment: The question ban isn't permanent. It'll expire after a period of time, or earlier if you edit the questions and the voting on them rebalances.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Except nobody has at all indicated *how* I should edit the questions. One guy suggested writing an entirely brand new program for the model drawing issue, but that would be absurd, especially since they assume I even have knowledge of writing and manipulating cameras to make such a thing practical. Yes, I am complaining about the question ban but I also want to know what is wrong with my questions (and answers to said questions) that is causing all these downvotes.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50

I do not see a bias against questions marked game-maker there. Most of those have several upvotes, and they are even unanswered.

Comment: @Almo I agree. I just figured its a point worth mentioning.

Comment: I feel this discussion is a bit of an over-reaction. Only one question has a "heavy downvote". I personally downvoted that question *almost a week ago*, and its score *has not changed*.

Comment: @Gnemlock I probably did exaggerate. I am mostly asking how I can improve my questions.

Comment: I would also like to point out, in comments, that if users do not think a question deserves an upvote on its own merit, *they should not upvote it*. Upvoting only to negate a downvote is, itself, bad voting practice.

Comment: @Gnemlock I'm not going to debate the practices of chat members. If you feel that is inappropriate feel free to go back a week or so and report those posts. I didn't ask them to upvote. They did that by their own merits, because they felt it didn't deserve the downvote. One of them was actually a person who had previously downvoted the post. Also, my other posts were about -4 before the upvotes, each. Two of them I see problems with but the one asking about rotations seems perfectly reasonable. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 6):

[Does Game Maker use use intrinsic or extrinsic rotations?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131729/do-game-makers-3d-rotation-transformations-use-intrinsic-or-extrinsic-rotations)

I don't think there's anything particular egregious with this question. The biggest issue I see is that you start out by discussing a "problem" with your rotations where they "don't see to work" but that's not what the actual title of your question, or the closing question, seems to actually be about. As such one could in theory excise everything but the very last paragraph for a more optimized question.

---

[Camera not working in a Game Maker mod I am creating](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131663/camera-not-taking-over-in-a-mod-of-a-game-maker-i-am-creating)

This one seems a bit more likely to attract the downvotes it has because it's essentially a code dump with the question "what's wrong here?" It doesn't help that you're being potentially too verbose again, which distracts from the issue and harms readability. In particular parenthetical statements like "(temp model until I figure out the proper model rotation algorithm)" just add noise to the question. That fact isn't particularly relevant but people still have to read and parse it.

I think you could improve this question by narrowing down the code to the point of failure and describing more about the context of the failure as your debugging has made you aware.

---

[Why won't my model display fully in a mod made with an older version of GameMaker?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131329/why-wont-my-model-display-fully-in-a-mod-made-with-an-older-version-of-gamemake)

This one has all the same problems of the "camera taking over" question; iy consists of a large code dump that is *very hard* to read because you've chosen to format it the way Game Maker requires of you rather than in a way that will help people here help you. It's not *as* wordy, in terms of superfluous statements, but it might be possible to tighten it up a bit.

It helps that you have an image, but originally you didn't, and that may have also contributed to the poor reception your question got.

Comment: In the third question the poor reception came *after* I edited the image in. Also, it's literally two lines of code in one line. That's not "unreadable" by any means. Also, I was told to do that because the code proved irrelevant to the answer and so I should try and make the question geared more in that direction. It didn't matter how I was drawing the model (there's really only one way to draw models) so I was told its better to just leave the useful version. Also, I made that edit last night after chat told me to do it.

Comment: You're right about the image, but as Gnemlock noted, votes are anonymous so all I can do is offer my own theories. You may assert that your code presentation is "not unreadable," but it is *entirely possible* that others disagree (I certainly do) and disagree to the point where they felt they should downvote the question. As is their right.

Comment: "I think you could improve this question by narrowing down the code to the point of failure and describing more about the context of the failure as your debugging has made you aware." I don't really see anything I could take out. As it is right now, it's the minimum it could be. Also, the point of failure isn't a bug in the code. The code is flawless. It's game maker being an idiot. So, I'm not entirely sure what I could remove.

Comment: I'd also like to take the time to point that it's very possible that others are voting on your questions based on the attitude you present in those questions or your follow-up comments. When you say things like "The code is flawless. It's game maker being an idiot," it doesn't help endear people to helping you. It makes you sound like a poor craftsman, blaming his tools. It's fine to *feel* that, but try to keep that kind of rancor to yourself and be objective about the problem.

Comment: Except what you dont understand is that issue has nothing to do with the code for the camera one. The issue was that game maker draws everything by this variable called depth *that it doesnt document anywhere*. I think anyone would agree that that is quite a bad problem to have. Also, I never posted anything like that in the question. Im only posting that here to point out that the code only has relevancy as context for others to see exactly what I was doing. I dont want my question closed for no context.

Comment: *shrug* You asked for advice, I offered some based on how I see you interacting with this site. That's all I can do. I cannot definitively explain why others vote the way they do and I will not engage in argument-by-proxy for them with you.

Comment: Im not asking for you to argue by proxy. Im just asking for suggestions to improve the question. It seems like your suggestions are saying to completely buldoze my question which just seems like a bit much. Surely they arent that bad of questions?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. I am suggesting you *focus* your questions and think about the presentation of the question to the audience you have. Not completely delete them.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, voting is anonymous. We can't really tell you why *any* of the votes have been placed, for sure, unless we were specifically the ones who placed them. [The closest bet is that Tim lost his keys, again.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught)

I feel I should also point out that I almost *always* see a direct link between "why have my questions been down-voted" questions and down-vote; that is, I see a direct pattern of these questions being down-voted *more* after the question has been raised, either through meta or comments. We can see this has already happened, here; since my original post, the question I personally down-voted has had one of its up-votes retracted. Another of your questions has received more down-voting, as well.

When the result of commenting on the amount of down-votes, I could only see the votes as a form of attitude punishment, which is bad form in its entirity. When these things are brought up, in meta, we have to assume that some users are simply being directed to your questions, agree with the downvotes, but do not agree that they should comment on why they are doing so. I still do not agree with this, but it's better form than criticing the question entirely off perceived attitude. Regardless, we can see that this is somewhat of the case, here.

*I will make comments where I have personally voted, below*.

---

> I have three questions that I have asked on the main site. Every single one of them have been downvoted quite heavily.

In essence, *only one* of your questions has been down-voted heavily. Both other questions sit at -1.

> ..to the point that I am longer allowed to ask questions (I checked out of curiosity;

As brought up in the comments, this is a temporary ban. If you do not need to ask any more questions at the current time, this is not a problem. Just ensure you pay heed to the feedback for future questions, as if it happens again, the temporary ban will most likely be for a longer period of time.

> I asked in chat twice (and some nice people upvoted the questions to try and counter-balance what they felt were unfair voting practices)

This, in itself, sounds like a problem. Your telling us that the up-votes come from users specifically because *they do not agree that the question should be down-voted*, which itself is a poor voting practice. If you do not agree that a question should be down-voted, *you simply don't down-vote it*. You should never award a question with up-votes if you do not think that the question actually deserves up-votes. We also can't tell, now, if *anyone* thought your question was useful, given that you've told us the up-votes were placed to negate the down-votes. I would not mind having a mod comment on this, as such practice sounds like the sort of thing that would even be revoked, if a pattern was picked up.

---

I personally down-voted your question [Why is game maker displaying a model without all of its polygons?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131329/why-is-game-maker-displaying-a-model-without-all-of-its-polygons), and did so for numerous reasons. I did so a mere 2 hours after your final edit, and can recall leaving your question at -5. As such, it appears that even this question has been mostly untouched, since your final edit. Ultimately, I voted that your question was **unclear** and **un-useful**.

#### If you were to improve the question, you could consider the following:

To quote you from the comments, "*@liggiorgio I'm not actually running this in game maker. Read the post very carefully. This is a mod of a game maker game*".
I had completely missed that you were not asking about using Game Maker, the first time I read your question. Your telling us that you *think* it was made in Game Maker 8. That is not helpful, *especially* if it is not important. You say it should not be important, *but why do you mention it*? It is good to remember that if the information is not important, it probably should not be there. Useless information can detract from useful information, and make your question look overly cluttered.

Your question appears to continue providing unhelpful information further down, where you appear to reprint duplicate code, simply for the point of presenting it in a more readable format. If you think that your code would look better presented in a different format, only present it in the different format. You can still refer to it, earlier, as "code snipper 1" or "my first code, below" or whatever.

#### If I were to improve the question, I would consider the following:

Please take this with a grain of salt, but I would personally delete the question, if it only came down to quality.

When it comes down to it, you were having a problem with a mod created by *SomeGuy*<sup>TM</sup>. When you have little information about the origin, it makes things particularly difficult. We do not know if *SomeGuy*<sup>TM</sup> is even remotely good at game developing, so for all we know, your problem could have been any number of inconsistencies resulting from author error.

At the end of the day, I'm confidant in saying that the only reason this question found an answer was that you were evidently able to find the answer without GameDev.SE. While your answer does point to something *interesting* in GameMaker (at least, in my opinion), there is simply not enough information in your question to accurately pinpoint the cause without personally playing around with your project. *This is still a problem*: How would anybody experiencing the same sort of problems find your question? *Not very well*, I would say.

Lastly, with a vote of -5, your question does not appear to regular users. As such, not many users are actually going to *be able* to up-vote. You have to ask whether it is worth cutting you losses. If I am not mistaken, you actually earn a medal for deleting a question with severe down-votes, so it's not all bad!

---

#### There *is* another option

Ultimately, you found your answer, so your not worried with attracting more attention to answer your question. You *could* tailor it to make it easier to find, if *other* users are having the problem. It *appears* that the problem *was* related to the mod being made in an earlier version of GameMaker. Why not rewrite the question to focus more on the fact that your importing a model into a GameMaker mod and having said problems?

From the looks of the answer, I suspect that your code had *nothing* to do with it. If that is the case, remove it. All of it. It might seem useful, but it might also detract users who *know* their problem is not a code problem, and immediately assume that yours *was*.

Make it short and sweet, and again, focus on the core problem. You might consider making the title more specific, as this is the first thing users will see. Something like "Why won't my model display properly in a mod made with an older version of GameMaker". Than, you could say "I know it is an older version, but the makers have unfortunately provided no specific information, and are not responding to my communications."

Comment: I was told by a moderator that I ***had*** to display the code in the better format below and that if I removed either code snippet from then on out, I would be sanctioned and the question deleted. I'd rather not bring up that point again.

Comment: Gnemlock: also, the code I provided is the minimal verifiable example. Granted, I do intend to regenerate the broken model tonight and upload it for reference. Might serve useful to anyone looking at the question deeply.

Comment: I edited the post. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131329/why-wont-my-model-display-fully-in-a-mod-made-with-an-older-version-of-gamemake Feel free to comment on the changes however you wish.

Comment: "I was told by a moderator that I **had** to display the code.." No, you weren't. You were told that the way you presented the code made for extremely poor readability and would likely reduce the likelihood that your question would be well-received.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, being told you had "poor readability" does not mean you should post a *second* version of the code, but regardless, you confirm the problem is not in the code. So your problem is not a programming one, and therefore, *any* programming would be moot.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I removed the code at one point and I was sent a post saying something along the lines of "stop deleting this or you will be punished"

Comment: @Gnemlock Thanks for the edits. It's not precisely the exact wording I would use, but they look awesome! I can see the improvements quite clearly!

Comment: No, you weren't. *None* of the comments on that question include the word "punish" or any implication of punishment. The closest thing I can see in the entire exchange is (from me): "Please don't revert formatting edits like that." Please stop casting aspersions.